# How to calculate new height and width for an image to fit with in predefined height and width, without affecting the image real aspect ratio in java?

Tags: java

I want to scale images to fit with in some predefined size without affecting the actual image's aspect ratio.

Do we have any predefined algorithms for that in java?

**Update:**

Resizing Like this. The output is the same image but in smaller size. The outside frame is just a mark.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you're going to have gaps in either the width or the height... the question is figuring out which.

```
double widthRatio = realWidth / definedWidth;
double heightRatio = realHeight / definedHeight;

if(heightRatio > widthRatio) {
    // scale image to match the height, and let the width have the gaps

} else {
    // scale image to match the width, and let the height have the gaps

}
```

Comment: @glowcoder: Thanks, for your answer. But how shall i  calculate the gaps?

Comment: if your frame width is 800, and sized image width is 300, you have 500 pixels of whitespace, so to center your image, make it 250 on either side

Comment: @Tami to generalize @iluxa's example, you have `int leftGap = (origWidth - newWidth) / 2;` and `int rightGap = (origWidth - newWidth) - leftGap;` This is of course biased to the left (as in either `leftGap == rightGap || leftGap == rightGap + 1`.)

Comment: @glowcoder: At first i am not able to understand. Now i am OK. Its cool.

Comment: @glowcoder: This solution is works for if `image width > image height`. If `image height > image width`, it fails. Any idea!!!

Comment: @glowcoder: To calculate new width, i used this `nWidth = (int)(FINALHEIGHT * origWidth)/origHeight;` Is that correct?!!